# Setting CSS values based on another value

Tags: css

I have a div that I want to set the height of to 1/2 the height of another div. Is there a way I can say something like `height: 50% of height of divid1;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With plain CSS there is no way you can do this. You'll have to use e.g. JavaScript to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('divid2').height = Math.floor(document.getElementById('divid1').height/2);
```

Or calculate half of the height of divid1 if the value is static.

Answer (score 1):

sorry, no, not in standard CSS.
Unless you want the height of the containing DIV, then ofcourse you can use 50%.
Maybe a solution for you would be to look into something like SASS (http://sass-lang.com/)